# Data is not getting saved in the database using sqlite database in android studio

Tags: java, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am a beginner in android development. I am making a keyboard app in android studio using java. I want to store the data whatever is being typed in database. I am able to get whatever is typed. I tried to store in the database. But its not getting saved there. Maybe I am not calling the database class properly. Please correct me where I am going wrong.

[Link for complete code including the XML files etc](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q93ANFSndVQADatzAXxQKQ4Dn_SdKB57/view?usp=sharing)

This is the code for the keyboard from which the database is called

```
package com.example.keyboard;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EDMTKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    private  boolean isCaps = false;

    String str="";
    String app;
    String app2;
    DBHelper DB;


    //Press Ctrl+O


    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard,null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this,R.xml.qwerty);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        DB = new DBHelper(this);
        return kv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int i) {

    }



    @Override
    public void onKey(int i, int[] ints) {

        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        playClick(i);


        switch (i)
        {
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                ic.deleteSurroundingText(1,0);
                StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer(str);

                if(sb.length() != 0) {
                sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1); }

                str = new String(sb);

                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
                isCaps = !isCaps;
                keyboard.setShifted(isCaps);
                kv.invalidateAllKeys();
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
                ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));



                app="App Name";
                app2="App name2";
                Boolean checkinsertdata = DB.insertuserdata(app,str);


                Toast.makeText(EDMTKeyboard.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                str="";


                break;
                //if(checkinsertdata==true)
                   // Toast.makeText(EDMTKeyboard.this, "New Entry Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //else
                  //  Toast.makeText(EDMTKeyboard.this, "New Entry Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




            default:
                char code = (char)i;
                char dup;
                if(Character.isLetter(code) && isCaps)
                    code = Character.toUpperCase(code);

                //if(str.length()==0)
                //{   dup = code;
                 //   str = Character.toString(dup);}
                //else
                str = str + code;

                ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
        }

    }

    private void playClick(int i) {

        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        switch(i)
        {
            case 32:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:


            case 10:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
                break;
            default: am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence charSequence) {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {

    }
}
```

This is the database class

```
package com.example.keyboard;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_name";

    DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase DB) {
        String createTable= "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "( appname TEXT PRIMARY KEY, data TEXT )";
        DB.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase DB, int i, int i1) {
        DB.execSQL("drop Table if exists " +  TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(DB);
    }

    public Boolean insertuserdata(String app, String str)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("APPNAME", app);
        contentValues.put("DATA", str);

        long result=DB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if(result==-1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }



}
```

The DB.insert() function returns true but the data is not getting saved. Please guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: *the data is not getting saved* did you extract the db from the device and found no rows in the table?

Comment: yes. There are no rows also

Comment: If DB.insert() returns a positive number then you can be sure that the row is added in the table. So the problem must be that you can't see/retrieve that row.

Comment: So Could you please tell me where does the problem may lie? (in the code or something else)I tried to open the database file using DB browser, there are no rows or columns.

Comment: You say that DB.insert() returns true. Did you debug the app with a breakpoint inside DB.insert()? You have a boolean variable `checkinsertdata` inside onKey() which you don't use. Use it to show a toast in case it is `true`.

Comment: checkinsertdata returns true. Could you please tell me whether this '' DB= new DBHelper(this); " is written in correct place? I think this is where it is going wrong

Comment: Since your app does not crash and checkinsertdata is true then the row is inserted in the table as I said in my previous comment. If there was a problem with `DB= new DBHelper(this);` you would get a null pointer exception and your app would crash. Use `rawQuery()` method to run a query that returns the rows of the table. Read more here: https://www.javatpoint.com/android-sqlite-tutorial

Comment: I changed the table to "           String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + KEY_SLNO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_APP + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DATA + " TEXT" + ")"; "    The error coming in logcat was " android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: table_name.appname" But I am not assigning the appname (KEY_APP) as Primary Key. So it is not necessary that the appname to be unique right? Please help me

Comment: Uninstall the app from the device so the db is deleted and rerun to recreate the db and the table. If the error persists try in a clean device.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
contentValues.put("APPNAME", app);
contentValues.put("DATA", str);
```

To

```
contentValues.put("appname", app);
contentValues.put("data", str);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a mistake. But still, the data is not being saved. Could you please tell me whether this '' DB= new DBHelper(this); " is written in correct place? I think this is where it is going wrong.